# Vue 3 - How to change data on one of multiple chid components?

Tags: vue.js, components, vuex, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 project where I have a parent component that loads other component that then loads another one that loads another one.

To give you an idea, I have a button component. The button is added multiple times in a set of numbers, the set goes into a card and the card goes into the main view component.

So 4 levels:

- Parent Main view component with X cards (in this case I only have one)
- Numbers Card component with X groups
- Numbers Group component with X numbers
- Number component used in Group

I have a binded var on the Number component that sets it active or not, by being true or false.

I want a way to set a function in my `<script setup>` tag in the parent top Main component (or one component inside of it) to turn one or multiple of the buttons components one and off (active true or false).

Does that makes sense?

I'm thinking if I need to use emit or just state data from my vuex data store. But I'm a bit confused on how to identify the specific button component (used multiple times) from the main parent 4 levels up component...

(In reality I want to add another type of button component there to activate that, toggle all other buttons on or off - But I think that if I understand how can from one function in one component I can access a variable in another set of components that will solve my issue...)

Let me know if this makes sense and if you can help me.

Feel free to point me to the Vue 3 Docs, I have been trying to find a solution but I'm not sure exactly where to look and because I'm using `<script setup>` new tag I think a lot of the examples there don't work for me.

Any little help is appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: With vuex you don't really need to identify the child components, the components  themselves subscribe to the state you are setting in the parent. e.g. `<button :active="some_vuex_var">`

Comment: Hi, my problem is I have my component multiple times, I don't know which vuex var to add...

I have `v-for` that renders multiple button components. Each button has their ID auto generated. Incremented digits. I could create multiple vuex state vars, one per button but that sounds overkill. 

I guess, my question now is: Does a component linked to a vuex var be included multiple times in a template making vuex var be cloned multiple times? So all vuex vars are virtually distinct for the multiple instances of the component even if I only have 1 entry in my store data for that var?

Comment: Also, I want to manipulate the button var inside my top level component `<script setup>` not from the `<template>` in fact from my top level component my buttons are inside another component so they are not even in my current component template...

Comment: @Matt I tested this. It's clever but it doesn't work for me. Because all my buttons are linked to the same var.
I can see a solution if I create all the buttons vars. But that sounds wrong.
I have a card that displays X buttons. It can be 40, it can be 60. 
So if I have 60 buttons I need to create 60 vars? And somehow parse that var id into my button component? This sounds weird because although I know in my app what is my maximum number of buttons (if need be I can put all individual vars), what if I didn't? There should be away for this to be more efficient, dynamic and flexible... How?

Comment: I'm now thinking maybe I just have two vars in my vuex store, something like `buttonsPicked` and `buttonsActive` and have them as arrays and then somehow filter to check if certain button id is in the array for each the `:active`, `:disabled` and `:class`. 
Does that sound like a good Vue 3 approach? I think it might be cleaner than defining all possible button ids in my state object. Right?

Comment: If you need individual control over each button then a button array containing the data for each sounds like a good approach

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I ended up using the Vuex variable as an array.

Then in my Button component I have this in my `<script setup>` for the isPicked variable, for example:

const isPicked = computed(() => {
  return store.state.session.btnsPicked.find(
    (i) => i === props.btn
  )
})

So my component variable now reacts to the Vuex states values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Matt. I ended up using the Vuex variable as an array.

Then in my Button component I have this in my `<script setup>` for the isPicked variable, for example:

```
const isPicked = computed(() => {
  return store.state.session.btnsPicked.find(
    (i) => i === props.btn
  )
})
```

So my component variable now reacts to the Vuex states values.